# Cambiar estilo de cota desde C# en Autocad 2016

Tags: c#, plugin

Estoy creando un plugin para Autocad 2016 el cual dibuja en el programa dependiendo de los valores que se carguen, me gustaria que se pueda acotar automaticamente todo el dibujo en dos estilos de cotas distintos. Logre crear las cotas de un mismo estilo pero no puedo cambiar entre dos estilos.

Ejemplo: Con este codigo acoto el largo total de la pieza dibujada, pero la pieza tiene unos circulos dibujados dentro llamados "Punchs" que tambien deben ser acotados pero con otro estilo de cota. abriendo un template de autocad donde ya estan precargados los estilos de cotas solo me queda intercambiar entre uno u otro.

```
 public static void AcoteSimple(double Ancho, double Largo_total)
    {
        var acDoc = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        var acCurDb = acDoc.Database;

        using (acDoc.LockDocument())
        using (Transaction acTrans = acCurDb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {
            var acBlkTbl = acTrans.GetObject(acCurDb.BlockTableId,
                                             OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTable;

            var acBlkTblRec = acTrans.GetObject(acBlkTbl[BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace],
                                             OpenMode.ForWrite) as BlockTableRecord;

            if (Ancho == 0)
            {
                Ancho = 300;
            }


            using (var dim = new AlignedDimension(
                new Point3d(0, Ancho, 0), new Point3d(Largo_total, Ancho, 0), new Point3d(0, 300, 0), "LARGO TOTAL: <>", acCurDb.Dimstyle))
            {
                acBlkTblRec.AppendEntity(dim);
                acTrans.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(dim, true);

            }
            acTrans.Commit();
        }
    }
```

Creia que iba a ser algo parecido al intercambiar entre capas como se ve a continuacion pero no dio resultado la adaptación que hice. (el codigo de abajo es el que uso actualmente para cambiar entre capas)

```
public static void Cambiar_Layer(string Layer_Select)
    {
        // Get the current document and database
        Document acDoc = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        Database acCurDb = acDoc.Database;
        acDoc.LockDocument();
        // Start a transaction
        using (Transaction acTrans = acCurDb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {
            // Open the Layer table for read
            LayerTable acLyrTbl;
            acLyrTbl = acTrans.GetObject(acCurDb.LayerTableId,
                                            OpenMode.ForRead) as LayerTable;

            string sLayerName = "";

            if (Layer_Select == "L1")
            {
                sLayerName = "L1";
            }
            else if (Layer_Select == "L2")
            {
                sLayerName = "L2";
            }
            else if (Layer_Select == "L3")
            {
                sLayerName = "L3";
            }


            if (acLyrTbl.Has(sLayerName) == true)
            {
                // Set the layer Center current
                acCurDb.Clayer = acLyrTbl[sLayerName];

                // Save the changes
                acTrans.Commit();
            }

            // Dispose of the transaction
        }
    }
```

Buscando por internet encontre este codigo que segun lo que dicen en el foro sirve para lo que necesito

```
 public void ChangeDimStlye()
    {
        Document doc = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        Database db = doc.Database;
        Editor ed = doc.Editor;
        using (Transaction trx = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {
            DimStyleTable dimTbl = (DimStyleTable)trx.GetObject(db.DimStyleTableId, OpenMode.ForRead);
            DimStyleTableRecord dimDtr = (DimStyleTableRecord)trx.GetObject(dimTbl["DimStyle1"], OpenMode.ForRead);
            ObjectIdCollection ids = dimDtr.GetPersistentReactorIds();
            foreach (ObjectId id in ids)
            {
                if (id.ObjectClass.IsDerivedFrom(RXClass.GetClass(typeof(Dimension))))
                {
                    Dimension dim = (Dimension)trx.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForWrite);
                    dim.DimensionStyle = dimTbl["DimStyle2"];
                    //dim.DimensionStyleName = "DimStyle2";
                }
            }
            trx.Commit();
        }
    }
```

Pero no hace absolutamente nada. en mi template de autocad tengo 2 Dimensions o Cotas que se llaman "DIM20" y "ACUM20" y son entre las dos que necesito ir cambiando para el dibujado de las cotas, pero no tuve éxito alguno.

como puedo lograr mi proposito hacer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> La solución fue sencilla, pude solucionar el problema con una correcta adaptacion del código para cambiar de capas.

```
public void ChangeDimStlye()
    {
        Document doc = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        Database db = doc.Database;
        Editor ed = doc.Editor;
        using (Transaction trx = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {
            DimStyleTable styletable = (DimStyleTable)trx.GetObject(db.DimStyleTableId, OpenMode.ForRead) as DimStyleTable;
            string NombreDeCota = "ACUM20";

            if (styletable.Has(NombreDeCota) == true)
            {
                // Set the layer Center current
                db.Dimstyle = styletable[NombreDeCota];
                // Save the changes
                trx.Commit();
            }            
        }
    }
```